# ExoPlayer how to control two audio files playback currently

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I have a task as below:

> Looping 1 audio file in raw folder as background music (background
>   effect) with smaller volume .

Currently play other downloaded audio file as normal.

> 1. Is it possible when use ExoPlayer ? if not, let me know other way
> 2. How to control play/pause/volume of two files separately

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create 2 objects of ExoPlayer: mainPlayer vs bgmPlayer
2. Each player controls its states:

`play:player.setPlayWhenReady(true);`

`pause: player.setPlayWhenReady(false);`

```
volume: player.sendMessage(mAudioRenderer, MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_VOLUME, volume);
```